# cstr literal in C++11, How to pass an (char* []) to a function

Tags: arrays, opengl, c++11, arguments

While wrapping around an OpenGL shaders I found an issue with one of the required arguments. A standard vertex shader has a source that is copied by OpenGL into an internal representation. A simplistic one could look like this:

```
static const GLchar * vertex_shader_source[] =
{
    "#version 430 core\n",
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{",
    "    gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0):\n",
    "}"
};
```

`GLchar` is defined as `char`, so this is essentially a cstr. I wrote a wrapper object that helps me create and destroy the shader (`GLuint` is an OpenGL handle). My problem can be broken down to look like the following function call:

```
GLuint shader_ptr = helper(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertex_shader_source);
```

I only need the vertex_shader_source for this single use. I would like to write something that uses the array initialiser to create the memory with an automatic scope. I do not want to use the C99 way of casting because I want to use the C++11 way of doing this.

`helper` is defined as follows:

```
GLuint helper(GLenum type, const GLchar * source[])
{
    GLuint shader_ptr = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shader_ptr, 1, source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader_ptr);
    return shader_ptr;
}
```

Deleting is not important for this question and handled in a destructor using `glDeleteShader`.

I tried the following and it would not compile:

```
GLuint shader_ptr = helper(GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
{
    "#version 430 core\n",
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{",
    "    gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0):\n",
    "}"
}
);
```

How can i call `helper` as a "one liner"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shader is a single string (instead of a list of strings, which is actually quite beneficial in places) make your helper simply accept a `char const *` instead of a `char const * const *`. That way you have a local symbol that you can take the address of:

```
GLuint helper(GLenum type, GLchar const * source)
{
    GLuint shader_name = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shader_ptr, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader_ptr);
    return shader_name;
}
```

You can call this with just the string as parameter:

```
GLuint shader_name = helper(GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
    "#version 430 core\n"
    "void main() {"
    "    gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);"
    "}"
);
```

Note the lack of surrounding `{` and `}` and that this is one long string literal, since there are no commas (`,`).

BTW: OpenGL does not give you pointers, but opaque object *names*.

---

#### A few words on programming style:

String literals like shader source texts are compile time constants. Like any kind of constant value it's bad style to write them in-place: If it were a number it's a "magic value" without meaning. And in the case of some string you now have to keep two parser states in your head when reading the source code (host program interleaved with the shader code). This largely reduces legibility and reduces maintainability.

Also your helper lacks error checking code.

In my projects, when using shader sources compiled into the program I use this helper (note that it actually ingests arrays to C strings):

https://gist.github.com/datenwolf/f108f2ed4085f3840457

```
GLuint load_gl_shader_from_sources(
    GLenum shader_unit,
    char const * const * const sources )
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shader_unit);
    if( !shader ) {
        goto failed_shader;
    }

    size_t n_sources = 0;
    for(; sources[n_sources]; n_sources++);

    GLint * const lengths = alloca(sizeof(GLint)*(n_sources+1));
    if( !lengths ) {
        goto failed_lengths;
    }
    lengths[n_sources] = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n_sources; i++) {
        lengths[i] = strlen(sources[i]);
    }

    glShaderSource(shader, n_sources, sources, lengths);

    glCompileShader(shader);

    GLint shader_status;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shader_status);
    if( shader_status == GL_FALSE ) {
        GLint log_length, returned_length;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);

        char *shader_infolog = alloca(log_length);
        if(shader_infolog) {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(
                shader,
                log_length,
                &returned_length,
                shader_infolog );
            char const * shader_unit_str = NULL;
            switch(shader_unit) {
            case GL_VERTEX_SHADER:   shader_unit_str = "vertex";   break;
            case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER: shader_unit_str = "fragment"; break;
            }
            fprintf(stderr,
                "\n %s shader compilation failed;\n%*s",
                shader_unit_str,
                returned_length, shader_infolog );
        }
        goto failed_compile;
    }

    return shader;

failed_compile:

failed_lengths:

    glDeleteShader(shader); 
failed_shader:

    return 0;
}

GLuint load_gl_program_from_sources(
    char const * const * const sources_vs,
    char const * const * const sources_fs )
{
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    if( !program ) {
        goto failed_program;
    }

    GLuint vert_shader = 0;
    if( sources_vs ) {
        vert_shader = load_gl_shader_from_sources(
            GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            sources_vs );

        if( !vert_shader ) {
            goto failed_vert_shader;
        }
    }
    
    GLuint frag_shader = 0;
    if( sources_fs ) {
        frag_shader = load_gl_shader_from_sources(
            GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            sources_fs );

        if( !frag_shader ) {
            goto failed_frag_shader;
        }
    }

    glAttachShader(program, vert_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, frag_shader);

    glLinkProgram(program);
    GLint linkStatus;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);
    if( GL_FALSE == linkStatus ) {
        GLint log_length, returned_length;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);

        char *program_infolog= alloca(log_length);
        if(program_infolog) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(
                program,
                log_length,
                &returned_length,
                program_infolog );
            fwrite(program_infolog, returned_length, 1, stderr);
        }

        goto failed_link;
    }

    /* shaders will get actually deleted only after the rogram gets deleted */
    glDeleteShader(vert_shader);
    glDeleteShader(frag_shader);

    return program;

failed_link:

    if(frag_shader)
        glDeleteShader(frag_shader);
failed_frag_shader:

    if(vert_shader)
        glDeleteShader(vert_shader);
failed_vert_shader:

    glDeleteProgram(program);
failed_program:

    return 0;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
void renderBoundingBox(mat4x4 mv, mat4x4 proj)
{
    char const * vs_sources[] = {
"#version 120\n",
"uniform mat4x4 mv; uniform mat4x4 proj;"
"attribute vec3 position;",
"void main() { gl_Position = proj * mv * vec4(position*2.-1., 1.0); }",
NULL };

    char const * fs_sources[] = {
"#version 120\n",
"void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0f); }",
NULL };

    static GLuint program = 0;
    static GLint attrib_position, uniform_mv, uniform_proj;
    if( !program ) {
        program = load_gl_program_from_sources(
            vs_sources,
            fs_sources );
        uniform_mv      = voglr_glGetUniformLocation(program, "mv");
        uniform_proj    = voglr_glGetUniformLocation(program, "proj");
        attrib_position = voglr_glGetAttribLocation(program,  "position");
    }

    if( !program ) {
        return;
    }

/* … */
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you pass a array of pointers you should pass the number of pointers in that array to openGL. This is the 1 you pass to `glShaderSource`.

```
GLuint shader_ptr = helper(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertex_shader_source, 4);

GLuint helper(GLenum type, const GLchar * source[], int nbSources)
{
    GLuint shader_ptr = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shader_ptr, nbSources, source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader_ptr);
    return shader_ptr;
}
```